# How do I show ADC values on my LCD screen using TouchGFX?

Tags: c++, stm32f7

I would like to show adc values on my lcd screen on the **stm32f746G - DISCO** board. The main challenge comes from integrating the TouchGFX software. This generates the model, view, and presenter files necessary to output widgets and wildcards. I believe I have set up my adc pin correctly, PF10, as I am able to get the ADC value in main.cpp using:

```
while (1)
   {
      HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc3);
      HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc3, 500);
      hullVoltage = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc3)*0.00080586;
      HAL_Delay(1000);
   }
```

But my main goal is showing this on my lcd screen. I have touchGFX setup where I can input a float to a wildcard in View.cpp. For example:

```
void Monitor_ScreenView::handleTickEvent()
{
     Unicode::snprintfFloat(textArea2Buffer, 4, "%f", 3.14f);
     textArea2.invalidate();
}
```

I will show you my model, view, and presenter cpp files to demonstrate where my issue lies.

**model.cpp**

```
#include <gui/model/Model.hpp>
#include <gui/model/ModelListener.hpp>

#ifndef SIMULATOR
#include "stm32746g_discovery.h"
#endif

void Model::getHullVoltage()
{
    HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc3);
    HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc3, 500);
    hullVoltage = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc3);
}
```

**View.cpp**

```
#include <gui/monitor_screen_screen/Monitor_ScreenView.hpp>
#include <gui/model/Model.hpp>

#ifndef SIMULATOR
#include "stm32746g_discovery.h"
#endif

void Monitor_ScreenView::handleTickEvent()
{
     Unicode::snprintfFloat(textArea2Buffer, 4, "%f", presenter->getHullVoltage());
     textArea2.invalidate();
}
```

**presenter.cpp**

```
#include <gui/monitor_screen_screen/Monitor_ScreenView.hpp>
#include <gui/monitor_screen_screen/Monitor_ScreenPresenter.hpp>

// my functions
float Monitor_ScreenPresenter::getHullVoltage()
{
    return(model->hullVoltage);
}
```

The only error I get from this build is "hadc3 was not declared in this scope" from model.cpp.

I would be very gracious if I could get any insight from my code. Other than this, my code works, as I am able to turn on and off an LED with a button on the touch screen, I am able to print a float on the screen where I want, and I am able to get the adc value in main.cpp. I just need it to show on the screen every tick.

Comment: Post the code where `hadc3` is declared. If you can't find such code - that's the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The code written in the view classes in a TouchGFX application should be portable, making it able to run in a simulator or on target. E.g. If you were to run your application using `gcc` through the TouchGFX designer on Windows, you'd have unresolved symbols for `HAL_ADC_`. Replacing the code with a call to the views presenter and then to the model would improve portability and would encapsulate the functionality better rather than keeping it inside an event handler.

Keeping target specific code inside the model and guarding it with `#ifdef SIMULATOR` would allow you to trigger simulator and target versions of the code from either a keyboard event, a tick event or an external event from the hardware.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how this addresses the specific error, "hadc3 was not declared in this scope", and what specific changes would be needed to OP's code?

Comment: I get your point, thanks. I've since learned more about what the format of an "answer" should be. At the time I was not able to share my general observation as a comment on @Marks post due to lack of reputation.

Answer (score 1):

If you use HAL library, you can use `#ifndef SIMULATOR` block

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found the answer to my problem. In View.cpp I declared hadc3 as an extern type:

```
void Monitor_ScreenView::handleTickEvent()
{
    extern ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc3;
    float hullVoltage;


     HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc3);
     HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc3, 500);
     hullVoltage = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc3)*0.00080586;

     Unicode::snprintfFloat(textArea2Buffer, 4, "%f", hullVoltage);
     textArea2.invalidate();
}
```

I don't think any other files were needed! Cheers ProXicT, and Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm curious why the library and its `#include`s don't make this declaration available, if they define that instance somewhere. Therefore I'm not sure this is a full solution.

Comment: It is considered "bad" practice to call target specific (e.g. `HAL_*` functions) from view code, since it makes the code less portable. I'd call `presenter->doStuff()` which then calls back to the back end (`Model`). Or at least sorround with `#ifndef SIMULATOR` so that the gui can be run on SDL through the Designer or Environment.